# Changing list inside dictionary into sets?

Tags: python, list, set, converters

For example, I have this that I opened from a .txt file:

```
{'fruit':['apple','pear'], 'veggies':['cucumber']}
```

How would I convert the items in the lists inside the whole dictionary into sets so it'll have the output:

```
{'fruit':{'apple','pear'}, 'veggies':{'cucumber'}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterate over all the keys in the dictionary, and reassign each key's value to be a `set()` of its current value:

```
for key in mydict:
    mydict[key] = set(mydict[key])
```

Comment: You could also do for `key, lst in mydict.items(): mydict[key] = set(lst)`

Answer (score 0):

If you iterate through the keys in the dict, you can cast the lists to sets.

```
d = {'fruit': ['apple', 'pear'], 'veggies': ['cucumber']}

for key in d.keys():
    s[key] = set(d[key])
```

This produces the output you want.